# Процесс создания классов

Tags: javascript, классы, наследование

Кто-нибудь может пожалуйста объяснить более доходчивым образом, почему так происходит?
Как я понимаю, в момент создания класса,не создания нового экземпляра, а именно написания самого класса - создается специальный объект,который будет находиться в название_класса.prototype.

```
class A {
        constructor(){}
        anotherOne (){
            return 1;
        }
    }

    A.prototype = null;
    let a = new A();
    console.log(a.__proto__) //Object {constructor: , anotherOne: }
    console.log(a.anotherOne()) // 1
```

Подскажите, почему когда я присваиваю A.prototype = null, всё равно работают методы класса?
Попытался узнать какие флаги стоят у поля constructor в A.prototype - undefined.
Возможно неверным способом пытался узнать.
Подскажите, как это работает?
Премного благодарен.

Comment: https://github.com/azat-io/you-dont-know-js-ru/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md

Comment: @kelter, ответы в ответы, не нужно писать ответ в текст вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Если запустить код в режиме 'use strict' - всё станет понятно.

```
 "use strict"
    class A {}
    A.prototype = null;
    //Cannot assign to read only property 'prototype' of function 'class A {}'
```